# Failed to build Qt statically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mingw32, building

I want to build Qt for my windows machine but it does not work.

I have done

```
git clone https://github.com/qt/qt5
cd qt5
perl init-repository
configure -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-g++ -static -release -opengl desktop -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -nomake examples
mingw32-make -j4
```

After a while, I've got some errors

```
AutoUic subprocess error
------------------------
The uic process failed to compile
  "SRC:/qttools/src/designer/src/components/formeditor/deviceprofiledialog.ui"
into
  "SRC:/qttools/src/designer/src/components/lib/DesignerComponentsPrivate_autoge
n/include/ui_deviceprofiledialog.h"
included by
  "SRC:/qttools/src/designer/src/components/formeditor/deviceprofiledialog.cpp"

...

Makefile:144: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/JN1tP0ZL

How can I fix it? Thanks for help